# Grab portion of URL with PHP

Tags: php

I have the following PHP to grab a part of the URL.

I have a URL *www.mysite.com/my-team2.php* and it echoes `my team` instead of `my team2`.

```
$page = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos(strtolower($page),'my-team') !== false) {
    echo 'my team';
} elseif (strpos(strtolower($page),'my-team2') !== false) {
    echo 'my team2';
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: because 'my-team2' contains 'my-team' ?  ie your first if is always true

Comment: Because `my-team2.php` also includes the string `my-team`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because it is finding the first instance first, the else if will never occur, what you should do is swap them

```
if (strpos(strtolower($page),'my-team2') !== false) {
echo 'my team2';
} elseif (strpos(strtolower($page),'my-team') !== false) {
echo 'my team';
}
```

so basically what it was doing without swapping them was finding the text 'my-team'

since the text 'my-team'is part of the text 'my-team2', it would always trigger the if without ever seeing the else if, because the if would always == TRUE.

by swapping them and putting the 2 first, 'my-team2' it will have to find that first, thus if the 2 is not in it, then the else if will trigger

Comment: What if url contains "my-team22" ? It's better to use reguler expressions.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `my-team` is contained in `my-team2`, so the first test is already true.

Either reverse them (rather simplistic) or use another approach, such as comparing the whole string or using a regular expression match.

Answer (score 1):

Because "my-team" is substring of "my-team2". It's better to use regular expressions on these kind of situtaions.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the most specific match in the first

```
echo strpos(strtolower($page),'my-team2') ！== false ? 'my-team2' : strpos(strtolower($page),'my-team2') !== false ? 'my-team' : '';
```